# Reference current component in React prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After browsing the section on components, props, and other similar areas on the React documentation, I can't seem to find if this is possible.

Trying to do something like this:

```
construct() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    category: dog
  };
}

render() {
  return(
    <input type="radio" category="dog" 
      defaultChecked={this.state.category === this.prop.category} />
    <input type="radio" category="person" 
      defaultChecked={this.state.category === this.prop.category} />
  );
}
```

In this case, the `radioInput` with `type="dog"` would get be checked by default, while the `type="person"` would remain unchecked.

Is this possible to do dynamically?

Comment: Yep, that should be possible

Comment: @Hamms could you provide an example or link to documentation? The current answers do not seem to understand my question.

Comment: Note that the "current component" in this case is the thing that defines the render method; the two inputs are simply Elements. You can create components for them to have them do what you want, or simply initialize them with something like `["dog", "person"].map(category => <input type="radio" category={category} defaultChecked={category === this.props.category} />)`

Answer (score 0):

First I would use the `checked` attribute in your case
Then for the default values, you just need a default state
Next to handle the changes just give your input the same `name`

*Edit*
To handle the state change, you should add an `onChange` callback (don't forget to bind it to your component) and instead of using `category` use `value`
The callback should have a [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event as argument, you can use `event.target.value` to get the new state value

Answer (score 0):

First you should know how to use 'type=radio' props in input HTML tag.You should first look at this document [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).Than you will find that your use of this property is wrong.You should add 'name' props for you .
You may use like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      category: "dog"
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      category: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="dog"
          name="animal"
          checked={this.state.category === "dog"}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="person"
          name="animal"
          checked={this.state.category === "person"}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: `defaultChecked` is a perfectly valid property in react https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: Yeah,i know,what i mean is the 'name' property should be added.